# Combine json and make arraylist<object>

Tags: android, json, arraylist

I have **JSON** that I want to combine data from 1st object into 2nd object

```
{
    "ViewId": {
        "56": {
            "ViewId": "56",
            "Name": "hi",
            "param": "value"
        },
        "88": {
            "ViewId": "88",
            "Name": "hi2",
            "param": "value2"
        }
    },
    "que": [
        {
            "RId": "123",
            "ViewId": "88",
            "Count": 0
        },
        {
            "RId": "456",
            "ViewId": "56",
            "Count": 0
        }
    ]
}
```

Basically from this I am making ArrayList, How can I add ViewId data in to que.
I want to merge JSON in following way:

```
{
    "que": [
        {
            "RId": "123",
            "ViewId": "88",
            "Name": "hi2",
            "param": "value2",
            "Count": 0
        },
        {
            "RId": "456",
            "ViewId": "56",
            "Name": "hi",
            "param": "value",
            "Count": 0
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: It is not clear what do you want. Please try to make your question more correctly. Use commas and Capital letters please.

Comment: You can run a loop for that and check for respective JSONObject  in the viewId array and modify that.

Comment: Do you want to merge elements of viewId into que? like 1st element of viewId should be merged into que's first element, right?

Comment: yes i want merge but as per der ViewId like ViewId of 88 should add into que whose view id is 88

Comment: Can you add information about what JSON library you are using? (if any?)

Comment: gson lib for string to model

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    JSONObject ViewIdJsnObject = new JSONObject(); //replace new JSONObject() with ViewId Json Object here
    JSONArray queArray = new JSONArray();//replace new JSONArray() with actual json array;

    //Traverse through all que objects in array
    if(queArray != null && queArray.length() > 0){
        for(int i=0; i<queArray.length(); i++){
            try {
                JSONObject queObj = queArray.getJSONObject(i);
                String queViewId = queObj.getString("ViewId"); //ViewId of que object at position i
                JSONObject viewIdObj = ViewIdJsnObject.getJSONObject(queViewId); //get json object against ViewId
                if(viewIdObj != null) {
                    //Now add these value to que object at position i
                    String name = viewIdObj.getString("Name");
                    String param = viewIdObj.getString("param");
                    queObj.put("Name", name);
                    queObj.put("param", param);
                }
            } catch (JSONException jse) {
                jse.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
    //Now que array contains final merged data, convert it to ArrayList<Your_model>.
```

Comment: queObj is not adding it will always overlap the data

Comment: You should add it to your array list directly then. Add que object first then add corresponding name & param values

Comment: JSONArray finalValue = new JSONArray();
 and then adding to finalValue.put(queObj) in for loop.
finalValue will have all data

Answer (score 1):

Make A class

```
public class Data {
    int id;
    List<Que> que = new ArrayList<Que>();


    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public List<Que> getQue() {
        return que;
    }
    public void setQue(List<Que> que) {
        this.que = que;
    }

}
```

Make Another class called `Que`

```
public class Que {
    int RId;
    int ViewId;
    int Count;


    public int getrId() {
        return RId;
    }
    public void setrId(int rId) {
        this.RId = rId;
    }
    public int getViewId() {
        return ViewId;
    }
    public void setViewId(int viewId) {
        this.ViewId = viewId;
    }
    public int getCount() {
        return Count;
    }
    public void setCount(int count) {
        this.Count = count;
    }

}
```

Use it using `gson`

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
        Data data = gson.fromJson(json, Data.class);
        List<Que> queList = data.getQue();
        for(Que que : queList){
            System.out.println("This is R ID" +que.RId);
            System.out.println("This is View ID" +que.ViewId);
            System.out.println("This is Count" +que.Count);
```

Make sure your json attributes name matches the java instance parameters.

Comment: @andro This will work. I am sorry, I was lazy. You have to figure out for other json fields like above "que" which is "ViewId": "56": { .... },....... },